Can you decipher this transliterated paragraph?
The following text printed in Cyrillic contains a transliterated paragraph in a language that does not use the Cyrillic alphabet. Decrypt it and translate it to English.
Hint:

 The target language that the encrypted message is written in uses an abugida.

Њин жиґ ла, њин жиґ ла қйод раӈ наґс ҵал ду сbоӈ нас ґло бур ду раӈ њид кйи бсам ҵул чес. Қйэд кйис до снаӈ бйас паги бйа ба лаӈ по ни ћи жиґ йин. Ҷес шас ҷе ба ни қйод кйис қйод кйи клад паги наӈ ґи скад сґра шэс срид.

Google translate outputs something for individual sentences.

The problem with making 3 questions and putting bounties on all of them is that your questions are competing with each other for attention.

@BenjaminWang, it's too late to remove the bounties now. That was basically a mistake.

Annoyingly partial answer. I believe this is

 either Tibetan or Dzongkha, either way normally written in the Tibetan script.

How to break in:

 There are a lot of modified letters not including to the standard Cyrillic alphabet, so we're probably looking for a language with a lot of sounds that are not found in Slavic languages. These are notably all consonants, and there are only six standard vowel characters (аеиоуэ) used in the entire text. Let's assume reasonable pronunciations for the unmodified Cyrillic letters, and try to pick some useful words to search for. The first one I picked was бсам ("bsam"), which looks like a weird enough combination to limit our search a lot. Wiktionary does not have the Tibetan word "bsam", but does have བསམ་བློ ("bsam blo"). So let's see if we could be dealing with either Tibetan or a closely related language.

Let's map the vowels first.

 Wikipedia has a helpful table of Tibetan letters. The vowels seem pretty simple to transcribe. Use а for the default vowel, и is marked with ི /i/, о with ོ /o/, у with ུ /u/, and we since there are only five vowel sounds we can assume both е and э stand for ེ /e/. In the end we can add ཨ to hold any vowel markers not belonging to a consonant letter.

Try to map the consonants next.

 The language does indeed seem to have a lot of consonant sounds not present in the major Cyrillic-script languages. Start with the unmodified Cyrillic letters whose standard pronunciation appears in Tibetan as is:

 к = ཀ /k/
 ч = ཅ /tʃ/
 д = ད /d/
 н = ན /n/
 п = པ /p/
 б = བ /b/
 м = མ /m/
 ж = ཞ /ʒ/
 й = ཡ /j/
 р = ར /r/
 л = ལ /l/
 ш = ཤ /ʃ/
 с = ས /s/

 Normally I would assign г to correspond to ག /g/, but noting that our script has both г and ґ, maybe it's like Ukrainian where the ґ stands for /g/ and the г would then be either ཧ /h/ or (more likely since it's a voiced sound in Ukrainian) འ /ɦ/. Note that we have no х in the excerpt, which would be a more natural choice for the /h/.

These can probably be inferred as well for completeness' sake, even though the letters don't apperar in our excerpt.

 т = ཏ /t/
 ц = ཙ /ts/
 з = ཟ /z/

Remaining consonants:

 Based on letter similarity, қ seems like a good candidate for ཁ /kʰ/. There are two variations of н, but both have a pronunciation in some Cyrillic-using languages that are close to what we need. So њ is most likely ང /ɲ/, leaving ӈ (en with hook) to correspond to ང /ŋ/.

 This leaves ҵ, ћ and ҷ unaccounted for. Here I resorted to some trial and error, e.g. ཆེས is an existing word in Tibetan, so ҷ = ཆ /tʃʰ/. Similarly, ҵ = ཚ /tsʰ/ seems to produce intelligible results, leaving ћ for ཛ /dz/.

So, best guess at the original passage in the correct script:

 ངིན  ཞིག ལ, ངིན  ཞིག ལ ཁཡོད རང ན གས ཚལ དུ སབོང ན ས གལོ བུར དུ རང ངིད ཀཡི བསམ ཚུལ ཅེས. ཁཡེད ཀཡིས དོ སན ང བཡས པའི བཡ བ ལང པོ ན ཨི ཛི ཞིག ཡིན . ཆེས ཤས ཆེ བ ན ཨི ཁཡོད ཀཡིས ཁཡོད ཀཡི ཀལད པའི ན ང གི སཀད སགར ཤེས སརིད

Trying this with Google Translate, it gives

 I'm going to go to the forest and suddenly I'm going to think about it. It is a rich man whom you have noticed. The greatest knowledge of the universe is the inner knowledge of the universe.

However, another possibility is:

 that the passage is not Tibetan after all but Dzongkha (which is written in the same script). When I type the passage above into the translator, it suggests trying Dzongkha instead. Translating as Dzongkha gives the following translation:


 I'm sure you'll like it. I'm sure you'll like it. You are the one who has done the right thing. The most important thing is that you know the meaning of your words.

The latter option seems like a slightly better answer for a question like this, but not sure how to narrow it down any more from here. Not 100% sure about all the letter correspondences here, especially among the weird fricatives. Maybe someone else with better grasp of the languages in question can finish it off from here. (There's also the chance that I'm completely on the wrong track, of course.)

Lbh ner pbeerpg gung guvf vf na rapbqvat bs Gvorgna. Ubjrire, guvf cnffntr vf jevggra va Byq Gvorgna, juvpu qbrf abg unir /gʃ/.
